# WCF Windows Service and non responsive UI

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, wcf, optimization

We have a core windows service hosting around 9 WCF service and acting as a client to another 3 WCF services. We have a front-end website that communicates with this windows service  through WCF.

At somepoint, the windows services is executing some heavy operations which results in 100% CPU utilization, usually split 60-40 between the windows service and SQL server.

This is where the WCF connection/requests between the website times out, and this results in a very non responsive UI.

I am looking for a way to make sure any UI-related WCF calls gets executed anyway and takes the highest priority.

Our main problem is that we need to stick with this deployment scenario, where the windows service, the website and SQL server are all running on one machine. We are required to maintain a responsive UI even with a 100% CPU utilization. I am not sure where to start looking for a fix for that ...

Comment: What you need is thread based operations in UI and in server Parallel computing if you have many cpu cores

Comment: What about queueing requests for the service? You could queue the request and use something like websockets for UI notifications. As far as your CPU load, you could try load balancing your service server. However, it can get tricky since you also have your DB server sitting on it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should split your service endpoint onto two separate hosts, one for high volume, or process-intensive operations and one for low latency operations. The high-volume endpoint would process from a queue offline, and the low-latency endpoint would handle requests synchronously from the UI.

The kind of problems you are having are typical of when you try to balance the conflicting resource needs of high volume and low latency together in the same process.

If you cannot scale out in this way then I can't really suggest much you can do about it and must apologize for not answering your question directly.

Another thing you could look at is moving everything asynchronous and using a pattern such as [CQRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CQRS) to provide separation between your read and write requirements.